# Normal form of a non linear system

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

Let the system:
$\begin{cases}
\dot{x_1}=a\sin{x_2}\\
\dot{x_2}=-x_1^2+u\\
y=x_1
\end{cases}$
that is:
$\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=
\begin{bmatrix} a\sin{x_2}\\
-x_1^2
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}u=f(x)+g(x)u\\
y=x_1
\end{cases}$
Since the relative degree is equal to $2=n$, I think, looking at the system, that since the input appears only in $\dot{x_2}$, the system is in normal form. But to be sure I have tried to write how it should be the system in normal form, so:
$\begin{cases}
\dot{\xi_1}=\xi_2\\
\dot{\xi_2}=\mathcal{L}_f^2h(x)+\mathcal{L}_g\mathcal{L}_fh(x)u\\
\end{cases}$
(where I have used the lie derivative for the notation and $y=\xi$)
The $\mathcal{L}_fh(x)$=$a\sin{x_2}$ and so $\mathcal{L}_f^2h(x)$=$a\cos{x_2}(-x_1^2)$.
Then $\mathcal{L}_g\mathcal{L}_fh(x)u$=$a\cos{x_2}u$, so $\dot{\xi_2}=a\cos{x_2}(-x_1^2+u)$.
So my question is: why there is the factor $a\cos{x_2}$ in $\dot{\xi_2}$ that there is no in $\dot{x_2}$, even if the original system seems to be normal? The system written in $\xi$ should be exactly equal, right?

Answer (score 1):

They are equal. What you basically do is a nonlinear state (and input) transformation to obtain a linear system basically. So you define a new input $v$ as
$$v = L^2_fh(x)+L_gL_fh(x)u$$
such that
$$\begin{align}
\dot\xi_1 & = \xi_2; \qquad (1a) \\
\dot\xi_2 & = v \qquad (1b)
\end{align}
$$
So if you draw this in a block diagram (I'll do it in text for now), you obtain:

--> [ NL transformation ] --> [original system] --> [NL transformation]$^{-1}$ -->

which is equal to

--> (1) -->

---

edit:
What you do to obtain a normal form is you first differentiate the output, such that you can obtain something like $y^{(n)}(t)+\cdots+\dot y(t) + y(t) = v(t)$. So:
\begin{align}
y &= x_1 = \xi_1 \quad \text{(first 'normal' state)} \qquad (2a)\\
\dot y & = \dot x_1 = \xi_2 \quad \text{(second 'normal' state)}\quad(2b)
\end{align}
We only have two state, so two 'normal' state should suffice. Furthermore, the jacobian of $[y, \dot{y}]^\top$ w.r.t. the state is full rank *around* the origin, so this is fine.

Next you calculate your dynamics of the normal system, which requires to determine the time-derivative of (2). This implies taking the derivative w.r.t. $x_2$ of $a\sin x_2$ (which is obviously $a \cos x_2$)

I hope this explains your question

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I have done and described above...the problem is that in $v$ appears the factor $a\cos{x_2}$ that is not present in the original form (so in $\dot{x_2}$)...why?

Comment: Because you take the derivative of the output w.r.t. time... Let me change my answer

Comment: It's all clear but what I can't understand is: if the system is in normal form, it is reasonable that my $\dot{\xi_2}$ will be exactly the original $\dot{x_2}$, but unfortunately it appears the factor $a\cos{x_2}$ and so $\dot{\xi_2}=a\cos{x_2}(-x_1^2+u)\neq (-x_1^2+u)=\dot{x_2}$...this is the point in doubt for me

Comment: I see your confusion. It is *not* true that $\dot\xi_2$ and $\dot x_2$ must be the same. When you transform the state, (so you basically map the state to a different space) the evolution of this transformed state changes with it. So, despite the input-output behavior remains the same, the state behavior or internal system behavior definitely changes accordingly!

Comment: @fill it is not true that the linearized state $\xi_2$ and $x_2$ are always equal. The original system is not in a normal form precisely because although $u$ affects $x_2$ in a "normal" way , $x_2$ doesn't affect $x_1$ in a "normal" way so $x_2$ has to change!

Comment: @Rollen by "$x_2$  doesn't affect $x_1$ in a "normal" way " do you mean that it is not true that $x_2=\dot{x_1}$?

Comment: @seaver so in essence as said Rollen the original system is not exactly in normal form!?

Comment: @fill Why do you think the system is in normal form (it is not)? Just because the input appears affine in the last equation? This is not the definition of a normal form. You get $\dot{x}_2 \neq \dot{\xi}_2$ because the first is *not* in normal form.

Comment: @SampleTime because the input appears only on $\dot{x_2}$, but maybe it is not sufficient

Comment: @fill As I said, this is not how normal forms are defined. So yes it is not sufficient that the input appears only in $\dot{x}_2$.

Comment: @SampleTime Ok thanks a lot!

Comment: @SampleTime, this is actually how normal forms in nonlinear control are defined (eq1 in my answer)... at least, this is how Khalil defined it, which is imo the father of NL analysis and control, defined it. See e.g. these slides: https://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearSystems/Sample/Lect_22.pdf

Comment: @seaver I was refering to the system $\dot{x}_1 = a \sin(x_2), \dot{x}_2=-x_1^2 + u, y = x_1$. *This* system is not in normal form, as you can also see on page 10 of your slides. The OP stated that he thought this system is in normal form, just because the input appears only in $\dot{x}_2$. As I pointed out, this is not sufficient, which is also proved by the slides you linked.

Comment: @SampleTime I agree, I think I misunderstood mr. OP :P. But the system can of course be brought into normal form as shown above. BTW @.fill, when the relative degree of a NL system is less than the order of the system, it still can be written into a normal form, however, you will end up with some (possibly unstable) unseen internal dynamics.